# Как сделать радиус окружности у этих углов?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

[image: Вот так должны выглядить края]

Я использую `svg path`. Мне нужно,чтобы была возможность  отрегулировать длину svg.

Вот мой код:

```html
 <svg viewBox="0 0 101 101"> 
      <defs> 
       <linearGradient id="Gradient1"> 
        <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0070d8"></stop> 
        <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#2cdbf1"></stop> 
        <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#83eb8a"></stop> 
       </linearGradient> 
       </defs> 
     <path d="M 50,50 m 0,-45 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,90 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,-90" fill- 
      opacity="1" stroke-width="1" style="stroke-dasharray: 282.783, 
      282.783;stroke-dashoffset: 62.783;transition: 0.5s all;stroke: 
      url(#Gradient1);fill: none;"></path> 
    </svg>
```

Мне надо закруглить эти края. Как мне это сделать?

[image: Вот так должны выглядить края]

Answer (score 13):

Длина в этом случае регулируется атрибутом path - `stroke-dashoffset`
При максимальном значении этого параметра равного длине окружности линия будет полностью скрыта.

При минимальном значении -`stroke-dashoffset="0"` -линия будет полностью нарисована.  При радиусе окружности  `45px` вашего патча полная длина окружности будет равна -

`2 * 3.14 * 45 = 282.6px`

- Изменяя значения от `282.6px` до нуля можно анимировать прорисовку
  линии.

  `<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="4s" values="282.6;0" begin="svg2.click" fill="freeze" />`
- Фоновую картинку лучше размещать внутри файла svg. В этом случае она
  будет адаптивна и верстка не сломается при изменении размеров окна
  браузера.

  `<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKgXe.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />`

*Анимация линии -  клик по картинке*

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
svg path {
 stroke-linecap:round;
 stroke-width:5;
 fill-opacity:0.5;
 fill:none;
 stroke: url(#Gradient1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 101 101" > 
  <defs> 
   <linearGradient id="Gradient1"> 
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0070d8"></stop> 
    <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#2cdbf1"></stop> 
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#83eb8a"></stop> 
   </linearGradient> 
   </defs> 
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKgXe.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
 <path d="M 50,50 m 0,-45 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,90 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,-90"  stroke-dasharray="282.6" 
  stroke-dashoffset="282.6">
  
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     dur="4s"
     values="282.6;62.783"
     begin="svg2.click"
     fill="freeze" /> 
  </path> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

Я сделал, как у вас на картинке - непоную прорисовку круга.
 Поэтому stroke-dashoffset изменяется от максимального значения `282.6;` до промежуточного `62.783`   Это параметр -  `values="282.6;62.783"`

*Для полной прорисовки круга необходимо задать `values="282.6;0`*

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
svg path {
 stroke-linecap:round;
 stroke-width:5;
 fill-opacity:0.5;
 fill:none;
 stroke: url(#Gradient1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 101 101" > 
  <defs> 
   <linearGradient id="Gradient1"> 
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0070d8"></stop> 
    <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#2cdbf1"></stop> 
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#83eb8a"></stop> 
   </linearGradient> 
   </defs> 
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKgXe.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
 <path d="M 50,50 m 0,-45 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,90 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,-90"  stroke-dasharray="282.6" 
        stroke-dashoffset="282.6">
  
 <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   dur="4s"
   values="282.6;0"
   begin="svg2.click"
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

### Решение CSS

Принцип действия тот же,- анимация атрибута `stroke-dashoffset`.

Но атрибуты патча и правила реализующие анимацию перенесены в `CSS`

```
stroke-dasharray:282.6;
  stroke-dashoffset:282.6;
  animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
   }
  @keyframes dash {
  0% { 
   stroke-dashoffset:282.6;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
```

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
svg path {
 stroke-linecap:round;
 stroke-width:5;
 fill-opacity:1;
 fill:none;
 stroke: url(#Gradient1);
 stroke-dasharray:282.6;
  stroke-dashoffset:282.6;
  animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
   }
   
  @keyframes dash {
  0% { 
   stroke-dashoffset:282.6;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 101 101" > 
  <defs> 
   <linearGradient id="Gradient1"> 
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0070d8"></stop> 
    <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#2cdbf1"></stop> 
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#83eb8a"></stop> 
   </linearGradient> 
   </defs> 
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKgXe.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
   <path d="M 50,50 m 0,-45 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,90 a 45,45 0 1 1 0,-90"  
   
  </path> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: Как всегда.....

Answer (score 5):

Нужно добавить атрибут `stroke-linecap="round"` в патч.

Comment: Спасибо, все сделал :)